# Virus messed with networking and cannot connect to the internet

Tags: networking, virus

I downloaded a program that ended up being malicious and compromised my computer. It installed a "Smartbar" Application and a few other applications that were probably keyloggers or something of the sort. I used Malwarebytes Anti-Virus to get rid of most of it, but I cannot connect to the internet now. I have run Kaspersky TdssKiller, however it returned showing that nothing was detected. I reset my hosts file as well. It says I have an internet connection, but none of my applications can connect to the internet.

Comment: Just my opinion: If my computer were ever to be infected by any malware, the first thing I'd do (and the safest thing to do) is wipe the whole drive and reinstall. This is why backups are necessary. I'd never risk the chance of continuing using the infected(or once infected) OS and have my private information stolen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Answer (score 0):

Once your machine is infected it will not allow you to go online or download any software.
In this case you need to download the files on another computer and then transfer them to the infected computer. You can transfer the files via a CD/DVD or USB flash drive.

Boot using safe mode and try running virus removal scanner.